# Как передать картинку в папке asset в Uri?

Tags: android, java

Гуру, помогите решить задачу. У меня в папке assets лежат картинки. У меня не получается передать их в Share. Я пробую такой метод, но он не работает...

```
Uri theUri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/data/img/0/0.gif");         
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,    theUri);
share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.message_share_subject));
String shareMessage = getString(R.string.message_share_body);
share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getString(R.string.title_sharedialog)));
```

Добавлю: читал, что решение есть ([How do I get a Uri to an image in my Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615509/how-do-i-get-a-uri-to-an-image-in-my-assets-that-will-work-for-the-searchmanager)), даже класс, но как им воспользоваться, я не понял =(

Answer (score 1):

Публикация данных проги во внешний мир в Android подразумевает их публикацию посредством реализации специального класса `ContentProvider`. В свою очередь, `ContentProvider` обеспечивает доступ к данным через `Cursor`, который в свою очередь разрешается `ContentResolver` в зависимости от MIME типа.

В примере который приведен у вас фактически рассматривается способ создания этого `Cursor`'а для специального кастомного Uri со схемой: `android.resource` ([см. синтаксис URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax))

Внимательно вкурите документацию к [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), изучите исходники в вашем примере и поймете глубину уровня абстракции создателей Android.

Comment: Хороший ответ, спасибо, но не решает проблемы. Желательно показать рабочий пример. Есть одно решение, это сделать копию папки asset на флешкарту при запуске программы. И работать уже с картой памяти.

Comment: Да, и еще ключи от квартиры где бабки лежат. Нет уж поработайте своим мозговым аппаратом